# I want the animation to work on the progress bar when hovering on an a element

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.choosebybrand {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, whitesmoke);
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 70px;
}

.choosebybrand img {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.choosebybrandtext h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 68);
  font-size: 40px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.choosebybrand h3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', 'cursive';
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.apple:hover h3,
.motorola:hover h3,
.lg:hover h3,
.samsung:hover h3,
.huawei:hover h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 68);
  transition: 1s;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icons a {
  margin: 10px;
}

.progress-bar {
  animation: pr 5s infinite;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes pr {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    color: red;
  }
  10% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  40% {
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: violet;
  }
  60% {
    background-color: rgb(184, 145, 145);
  }
  70% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  80% {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 234);
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="choosebybrandtext">
  <h1>Choose by Brand</h1>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 50px" data-aos="fade-in" class="choosebybrand">
  <div class="samsung">
    <a href="samsung.html">
      <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="images/samsung.png" height="232px" width="115px" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Samsung</h3>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="apple">
    <a href="apple.html">
      <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="images/apple.png" height="232px" width="115px" alt="">
      </div>
      <H3>Apple</H3>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="lg">
    <a href="lg.html">
      <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="images/LG.png" height="232px" width="115px" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Lg</h3>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="motorola">
    <a href="motorola.html">
      <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="images/Motorola.png" height="232px" width="115px" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Motorola</h3>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="huawei">
    <a href="huawei.html">
      <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="images/huawei.png" height="232px" width="115px" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Huawei</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const element = document.querySelector(".element")
const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar")


element.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  progressBar.style.animation = "pr 5s infinite"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to put an `eventListener` on the element.

```
const element = document.querySelector(".element")
const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar")


element.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  progressBar.style.animation = "pr 5s infinite"
})
```

make sure to replace `.element` with your own class

Comment: Its not working @Rishi Ghosh

Comment: Can you go into further detail about what happened and also tell us what element you want to hover over